# How to replace the second instance just once using awk

Tags: linux, unix, awk

The following script seems to replace every second instance. - Any ideas how I can adjust the awk command so that it replaces the second instance just once?

Script location refers to a file called basicTest.jmx, which contains the following txt

```
hashTree
hashTree
hashTree
hashTree
hashTree
hashTree
hashTree
```

Here's the script:

```
scriptLocation="basicTest.jmx"

myVar="FOOO__BARRRR"

awkOut=$(awk -v s='hashTree' -v myVar="$myVar" '$0~s{c++} c==2{sub(s, myVar); c=0} 1' "${scriptLocation}")  
echo "$awkOut" > $scriptLocation
```

This is what I need the output to look like:

```
hashTree
FOOO__BARRRR
hashTree
hashTree
hashTree
hashTree
hashTree
```

This is the current erroneous output:

```
hashTree
FOOO__BARRRR
hashTree
FOOO__BARRRR
hashTree
FOOO__BARRRR
hashTree
```

Comment: Are you sure you have to reset c=0 in your script?

Comment: I removed the c=0 and hey bingo it worked-Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

removing c=0 fixed the problem: Working version below.- Thanks all for your assistance.

```
awkOut=$(awk -v s='hashTree' -v myVar="$myVar" '$0~s{c++} c==2{sub(s, myVar); } 1' "${scriptLocation}")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk -va=hashTree -vb=FOOO__BARRRR '$1~a&&++c==2{$1=b}1' filename
hashTree
FOOO__BARRRR
hashTree
hashTree
hashTree
hashTree
hashTree
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to you answer so that others can readily understand your code.

Comment: @Brody Sorry! My English bad. I can't use English explain